# Is a product of two modulus functions the modulus of the product of the functions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I would just like to ask a simple question:

Is the following statement true? And is there a simple proof for it? $$|f(x)| \cdot|g(x)| = |f(x)\cdot g(x)| $$

Comment: Is $|ab|=|a||b|$ always?

Comment: @AnginaSeng when is it not precisley

Answer (score 8):

For $a\in\Bbb C$, by definition $\lvert a\rvert=\sqrt{a\overline a}$. Since, for non-negative real numbers $a,b$, the identity $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt a\sqrt b$ holds, it can be observed that $$\lvert ab\rvert=\sqrt{ab\overline{ab}}\stackrel{\left(\overline{z\cdot w}=\overline w\cdot\overline z\right)}=\sqrt{ab\overline b\overline a}\stackrel{\left(w\overline w\in[0,\infty)\right)}=\sqrt{a\overline a}\sqrt{b\overline b}=\lvert a\rvert\lvert b\rvert$$

The special case where $a,b\in\Bbb R$ has the same passages with $a=\overline a$ and $b=\overline b$. A subtlety might be the fact that, for most textbooks, $\lvert a\rvert=\sqrt{a^2}$ is considered a theorem, rather than the definition of $\lvert a\rvert$. There is very good reason to make that choice, but it is in principle just a matter of taste.

Comment: I was just a little confused by $a$ being complex and $a, b$ being real in the next sentence. The equation that follows in the next line has $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is true.

By definition (in $\mathbb R$) $$|x| =\begin{cases}x, &x\geq 0\\ -x, &x<0\end{cases} $$
Strictly speaking, there are four cases to consider, but effectively, we can make do by checking three cases.

## 1

Let $a,b\geq 0$, then $$ |ab| =ab = |a||b| $$

## 2

Let $a\geq 0, b<0$, then $$|ab| = -ab = a(-b) = |a||b| $$
For the last case, you would have to check this for $a<0$ and $b<0$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, $|a|\cdot|b|=|a\cdot b|$ holds for all real numbers. One proof is by considering the four cases

- $a\ge 0, \, b\ge 0,$
- $a<0, \, b\ge 0,$
- $a\ge 0, \, b< 0,$
- $a<0, \, b< 0.$

It also holds for complex numbers, btw.

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact that $|x| = x\cdot\text{sign}(x)$. Then,
$$|x||y| = \text{sign}(x)\text{sign}(y)(xy) = \text{sign}(xy)(xy).$$

Comment: I like the signum approach, but you would have to prove the last equality, which is more or less the same as proving the initial problem.

Comment: @AlvinLepik You're right, but you don't have to work with the other definition of absolute $x$.

Comment: @A.Molendijk But now you have to work with signum, which is defined using three different cases, not two like absolute value.